# Online / internet banking

Tags: anonymity

Am I still anonymous if I enter my bank card # and password when I log onto internet banking?

I bank with the Royal Bank in Canada. Thanks.

Comment: Define anonymous. Your bank knows who you are, and can see when you log in. They will be able to tell that you are logging in from Tor. However, your ISP (and other people on your local network) will not be able to see the website you are visiting.

Answer (score 2):

Like SuperSluether says, and as with any service you authenticate by logging in, your location isn't known to the service. You get location anonymity if you will.

On the other side of the connection, your local network, you get all benefits just like with any website or connection.